# Getting incorrect output with the for each in Java

Tags: java, loops, web-scraping, jaunt-api

I have an XML feed like below and am using Jaunt API for its parsing:

```
<item>
  <pubdate>12 march
  </pubdate>
</item>
<item>
  <pubdate>15 march
  </pubdate>
</item>
```

I wrote the following code

```
Elements i =agent.doc.findEach("<item>");
{
   for (Element item: i)
   {
       String pubDate=i.findFirst("<pubDate><![CDATA[]]>").innerHTML();

       pubDate=new StringBuilder(new StringBuilder(pubDate.substring(9)).reverse().toString().substring(3)).reverse().toString();
       System.out.println(pubDate);
```

I'm still getting the same output, like `12 march`, `12 march` etc., instead of `12 march`, 
`15 march`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `findFirst("<pubDate><![CDATA[]]>").innerHTML();` on `i` , instead call it on `item`.

Secondly, you may still get all 12 march because the feed that you are scraping might be published on 12th march, but note the time. It will be different in each case. That means your code is working fine.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

There is no need to use StringBuilder.Here is the shorter and precise code.

```
Elements i=agent.doc.findEach("<item>");
            for(Element item:i)
            {
                System.out.println(item.findFirst("<pubDate>").findFirst(Comment.CDATA).getText());
            }
```